# What range of time can I use when saying "It's morning already, please get up" and "It's night already, please go to bed"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

What range of time can I use when saying "It's morning already, please get up" and "It's night already, please go to bed"?

Chatgpt says

> When you say "It's morning already, please get up," you are typically
> referring to the early hours of the day, which usually range from
> around 6:00 AM to 10:00 AM, depending on individual schedules and
> lifestyles.
>
> Similarly, when you say "It's night already, please go to bed," you
> are typically referring to the later hours of the day, which usually
> range from around 8:00 PM to 12:00 AM, depending on individual
> schedules and lifestyles.

Now is 5am or 11 am, can I say "**It's morning already, please get up**"?

Now is 7pm, can I say "**It's night already, please go to bed**"?

Comment: This depends at least somewhat on when daybreak and nightfall occur. 7pm may or may not be nighttime depending on your location and time of year, and you of course would not say it's night if the sun is still up.

Comment: Most Anglophones live at latitudes where there's considerable variation in the hours of light or darkness through the year, so we *don't* normally use ***light, morning, dark, night*** as per OP's examples. We usually say ***It's late!*** - which is relative to (constant) ***clock time***, not (variable) ***"sun time"***. Today, only low-tech farm workers are likely to hear *It's **light** already! Time to get up!* You wouldn't often say *It's dark already. Time to go to bed.* In Scotland it might be dark before children have had their tea, so it's a bit mean to pack them off to bed hungry!

Comment: Are you asking what constitutes the morning and night? You should be able to get that from a dictionary. There's nothing in these phrases that is non-standard. Note that ChatGPT is just a program that generates random strings of words according to a probabilistic algorithm and doesn't know anything.

Comment: We don't use those;. We say bedtime and time to get up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Or the reverse - see RLS [Bed in Summer](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43190/bed-in-summer)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are absolutely no rules here at all

"Night time" or "bedtime" is entirely a parenting decision, as is "wake up time".  In the UK it is very normal for children to go to bed while the sun is still above the horizon during summer.  Conversely, in winter it is dark by 4pm, and still dark at 8am, so children will go to bed and probably wake up in the dark.

When you choose to tell your children that it is "bedtime" is entirely a parenting decision.